# Should I check for multiple rows if I limit it to one? (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm converting from MySQL to MySQLi and I noticed that if I am limiting to one row in the mysql query, is it necessary for me to check if the number of rows is 1? After all, the rows that can be returned is 0 or 1.

Here is the code I currently use (untested as I am converting from mysql to mysqli):

```
$query = "SELECT email,auth,username FROM user_list WHERE id = '".$user["id"]."' LIMIT 1";
$query = $mysqli->query($query);

if($query and $query->num_rows() == 1)
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you should check is that if a query returned 0 or more rows. 
It won't return more than specified by `LIMIT` clause, but it can return 0 if no matches found.

---

Btw, MySQLi is just an extension that allows you to access the functionality provided by MySQL 4.1+. It's still the MySQL.

Comment: Yeah, but if anything, I prefer using OOP. Since I am new to OOP with php (I've worked with oop in another language), I figured using mysqli to understand how oop works in php would be easy.
 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, it's guaranteed that you won't be returned more rows than specified in the `LIMIT` clause. You have no need to worry about being given more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query contains a `WHERE` clause on the primary key of your table, it will NEVER return more than one row.
Therefore, in this query, the `LIMIT 1` is completely useless (but not wrong at all).

I would remove it.

```
$query = "SELECT email,auth,username FROM user_list WHERE id = '".$user["id"]."'";
$query = $mysqli->query($query);

if($mysqli->errno==0 and $query->num_rows == 1)
{
```

Comment: Yes, but does MySQL do this automatically (limit to one row if its a primary key. I already know it will return one row, but why loop the other rows if one row is only going to be returned)

Comment: There's no loop in the code above. By definition, a primary key doesn't allow several times the same value in the column. So, the WHERE clause can't return more than one row!

Comment: Yes, the WHERE clause can't return more than one row due to obvious reason, but SQL still loops all the rows in the table. Limit 1 stops looping the rows of the table after the one row was found. This is optimised.

Comment: You are wrong. The MySQL engine is smart enough to optimize correctly without the `LIMIT 1` clause. Compare these 2 queries: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `user_list` WHERE id=1` and `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `user_list` WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1`. You'll see the output is the same because MySQL knows there is WHERE clause on the primary key and it will return at most one row. [Read documentation for EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)

Answer (score -2):

There's no need to check for the number of rows at all. You should only check if the query returned the data you need.

```
$query = $mysqli->query($query);
$single_row = $query->fetch_assoc();

if($single_row) {
    // There was some data returned. 
}
```

The same applies to queries that can return more than one row.

```
$query = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if($data) {
    // There was some data returned. 
}
```